# printf gives a warning when calling a function that is passing a variable by reference

Tags: c

So I have two functions, one function is passing by reference a variable and the other one is returning the result.

```
void dailyMiles(int *totalMiles)
{

    int milesDriven, totalDays, totalPeople;

    peopleInVehicle(&totalPeople); //calling other function
    daysPerWeek(&totalDays); // calling other function

    printf("Enter the amount of miles driven per day: \n");
    scanf("%d", &milesDriven);


    *totalMiles = (milesDriven * totalDays * 52 / totalPeople) * 2;

    printf("Total miles saved: %d\n", totalMiles);

    return;
}

int outputMiles()
{
    int totalMiles;

    dailyMiles(&totalMiles);

    return totalMiles;
}
```

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out why it gives me this warning in the terminal:

```
main.c:38:36: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type
  'int *' [-Wformat]
    printf("Total miles saved: %d\n", totalMiles);
                               ~~     ^~~~~~~~~~
```

You are probably wondering why the `dailyMiles` function's datatype is
`void`; well, I'm calling other functions that ask for users input so
whenever I call it in my main, it asks for users input two times.

Comment: What I'm actually wondering is why you posted all that code when your problem can be reduced to `void foo(int *miles) { printf("%d", miles); }`.

Comment: @melpomene this is part of a car pool assignment, hence the other code.

Comment: But your question isn't about your assignment, it's about this specific warning. When you have a question about the behavior of code you've written, you're supposed to create a [mcve]. "Minimal" means all non-essential parts of the code should be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to print the pointer itself (`totalMiles`), you want to print what it points to (`*totalMiles`).

```
printf("Total miles saved: %d\n", *totalMiles);
```

Answer (score 2):

In function `void dailyMiles(int *totalMiles)`
at statement 10: `printf("Total miles saved: %d\n", **totalMiles**);`

Instead of using `totalMiles` You should use `*totalMiles` because you created an integer type pointer. To access the data inside it you will have to use the asterisk operator that is *

For example:

```
int *totalMiles;
...
...
...
printf("Total miles saved: %d\n", *totalMiles);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the function totalMiles dailyMiles (int *totalMiles), totalMiles is a pointer to an integer. So, to print its values just add * in front of totalMiles as given below:

```
void dailyMiles(int *totalMiles)
{

int milesDriven, totalDays, totalPeople;

peopleInVehicle(&totalPeople); //calling other function
daysPerWeek(&totalDays); // calling other function

printf("Enter the amount of miles driven per day: \n");
scanf("%d", &milesDriven);


*totalMiles = (milesDriven * totalDays * 52 / totalPeople) * 2;

printf("Total miles saved: %d\n", *totalMiles);

return;
```

}

Hope this helps you. If it isn't working kindly let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to "dereference" your `int*` (pointer) to get an `int`.